# How to know new co-ordinates after rotation in processing 2

Tags: rotation, processing

I have a sketch where I am using several images. One of the images is being translated and rotated.
After PopMatrix how do I know the new position (X.Y) of image that has been moved around ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `modelX()` and `modelY()`. See the example below, which draws ellipses instead of images:

```
void setup(){
  size(600, 600, P2D);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotate(1.23);
  int x1 = 100, y1 = 100;
  ellipse(x1, y1, 10, 10);
  // store translated / rotated coordinates
  float x2 = modelX(x1, y1, 0);
  float y2 = modelY(x1, y1, 0);
  popMatrix();

  // draw red dot with stored coordinates
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(x2, y2, 2, 2);
}
```